# How can I automate NFT generation via code?

Tags: solidity, web3.py, python, nft

Pardon me if I sound lame.

I have read tutorials about creating NFT in Solidity but those examples were for a single item. How sites like Openseas create NFT contracts on the fly, especially when you have to mention JSON files and other things. Do they literally create a new `*.sol* file for each uploaded item?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What they may be implementing is called a contract factory pattern.  One would have a deployed contract, the "factory", responsible for calling the constructor of the new contracts and then keeping track of their addresses.

Helpful (and short) article:

https://research.csiro.au/blockchainpatterns/general-patterns/contract-structural-patterns/factory-contract/

Youtube video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Es0AfhcyXx0